# Create User in rails backend using Twitter Reverse Auth

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, omniauth

I am building an iOS app with a backend / companion website written on Rails.

I have set up devise and omniauth-twitter as outlined in the rails cast
http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised

I have also performed twitter reverse auth to obtain a oauth token on the devise as outlined here
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth

Now what I want to do is to send the token to the server and create a devise User in my DB.
What is the ideal way to create the user? Is this scenario supported out of the box with my current setup or do I have to write a little custom code?

Answer (score 1):

I have been researching the same thing for a few days.

I believe `omniauth-twitter` does not work with Twitter reverse authentication.

I think the solution is to send the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` you received
from the reverse authentication process on iOS, to a custom endpoint in your application.
Note, I am in the process of implementing this myself; it should work, but it's not tested yet.

There you would use the twitter API to to verify the credentials. This is the actual authentication step from the rails app's perspective. Something like this (untested code):

```
  consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(TWITTER_APP_ID,
                                 TWITTER_APP_SECRET,
                                 { site: 'https://api.twitter.com' })
  access_token_token = ::OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer,
                                                params[:oauth_token],
                                                params[:oauth_token_secret])
  MultiJson.load(access_token.get('/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_entities=false&skip_status=true')).body
```

(This is the same thing that the `omniauth-twitter` gem does after it gets the access token)
So from here on you would need to:

- Handle non-200 response from the above request
- Read the user ID from the returned hash, search your database for an existing user with an existing twitter user ID. If one exists, sign him in. If not, create a new user and sign him in.

Here's some more info:

- My first idea was to hit the twitter callback provider by `omniauth-twitter` directly. But in that case you would need to pass along 2 parameters: the `oauth_token` which is the request token you obtain from the reverse auth on iOS, and `oauth_verifier` parameter which I have no idea how to get on iOS (Using the standard web flow where the user is redirected back to your callback, this parameter is being passed from twitter).
- A downside with reverse auth seems to be that you need to embed the App secret in your application binary. It looks like a good idea to perform this step server-side (I saw the idea here: https://github.com/drudge/passport-twitter-token/#performing-twitter-reverse-auth-step-1-server-side)

Comment: Yea after playing around with it and thinking about the situation I kinda came to the same conclusion of performing the reverse auth on the server in order to avoid embedding the app secret in the binary.    

    
I also wanted to call the omnitauth-twitter callback directly but yea that isn't going to work. I found an omniauth provider [omniauth-twitter-access-token](https://github.com/tdegrunt/omniauth-twitter-access-token) that does what we want but it doesn't seem to be in the public gem repo. I am not sure what its support status is.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a UIWebview when the user clicks on the 'Sign up through twitter' button on in your ios which then follows the same process as my rails app.

Once the user has signed up through twitter, all handled by the server, you can then redirect back into your ios app signed up and logged in thus not having to handle all the tokens and requests in the app.